# How to convert route params to query params in Lumen routes

Tags: lumen

I am building a REST api with Lumen and encountered a problem that I did solve, but perhaps there is a more elegant way.

I have two routes:

```
$app->get('profile/{profileId}', \App\Http\Controller\ProfileController::class . '@show');
```

and

```
$app->get('post', \App\Http\Controller\PostController::class . '@index');
```

A profile can have many posts, so I want to build a new route that is like this

```
$app->get('profile/{profileId}/post', \App\Http\Controller\PostController::class . '@index');
```

to get the posts of a profile.
But I don't want to pass the {profileId} as route param to the index action of the post controller, but as a query param.

To solve this, I changed the route to this

```
$app->get('profile/{profileId}/post', function ($profileId) use ($app) {
    $controller = $app->make(\App\Http\Controller\PostController::class);

    $request = $controller->getRequest();
    $request->query->add([
        'profileId' => $profileId,
    ]);

    return $controller->index($request);
});
```

Had someone to do the same and has a better, more convenient way to do it?

I know e.g. that I could use the dingo package to do internal request from one controller to another, but I can not use it right now.

Comment: Off-topic question: why are you using `::class` notation? `PostController@index` should be fine, no?

Comment: Just by our convention, this way we easyly find all usages of a class.